# Cakephp 2.0: Htmlhelper throwing array_merge() error when using Html->script()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, html-helper

I am using the following code to implement some jquery-ui functionality:

```
<?php  $this->Html->script(array(
                              'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js',
                              'jquery-1.6.2.min.js'
                                ), 
                           null,
                           array(
                                'inline'=>'false', 
                                'once'=>'true'
                                 ) 
                           ); 
?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('.cv .collapsable').click(function() {
            $(this).next().toggle('slow');
            return false;
        }).next().hide();
    });
</script>
```

The target elements/classes are a  element and nested  elements. The jquery functionality is working, however, at the expense of php array_merge() errors like so:

```
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php, line 478]
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php, line 478]
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php, line 478]
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? I've tried just adding the `<script>` tags to the default.ctp layout, but couldn't get the URLs to work out either. I've done this with cakephp 1.3 so I am a little boggled at the problem I'm having now. Any help would be much appreciated.

### **UPDATE**

So this is my complete code:
The PHP:

```
<?php  $this->Html->script(
    array(
       'jquery-1.6.2.min'
    ),
    null,
    array(
        'inline'=>'false', 
    ) 
);  ?>
```

The jquery:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.collapsable').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I have removed the jquery-ui script to simplify things—when I do, I am only throwing two "array_merge" errors, now. Still, if I remove 'null'—which shouldn't even exist since the function only takes two parameters—I lose all functionality (the errors also go away).

But things get wierder!

I took a look into cake->core->lib->helper->htmlhelper and examined the function; it's got a line that checks to see if the `$options` array is a bool. If I instead use this code:

```
<?php  $this->Html->script(
        array(
            'jquery-1.6.2.min'
        ),
        false
);      ?>
```

I lose the capacity to specify either `inline = true` or `once = true` however I at least gain full functionality without the `array_merge()` errors. Is this a bug in 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html?highlight=script#HtmlHelper%3a%3ascript), the `$this->Html->script()` only accepts 2 parameters.  Remove the `null` and you should be fine.

Also, you shouldn't include the `.js` at the end of your script file names.

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
$this->Html->script(
    array(
       'jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min',
       'jquery-1.6.2.min'
    ),
    array(
        'inline'=>'false', 
        'once'=>'true'
    ) 
); 
?>
```

Comment: So I tried, initially, what you have here. Here's the bizarre thing: the example given in the [API](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/html-helper#method-HtmlHelperscript) shows the 'null' parameter, while of course the documentation link you shared does not indicate a third parameter at all. Yet, if I *don't* include it cakephp will not print the scripts, whereas when the `null` parameter *is* present, it works but with the error noted in my initial question. I am confused, lost, and dismayed. :P

Thanks for the tip on the file extension though.

Comment: Have you tried without the file extensions?  Also try removing the 'once' parameter (just for fun).  I use this code almost daily, and I NEVER include the `null` - just the above code (but I don't use 'once').

Comment: Copy/paste the exact code you're using (removing the null and .js extensions).  Just add it to your question as an "EDIT", or if you don't have permission, add it as a comment to your question with http://bin.cakephp.org/